# Slow startup time for Spring Boot apps

Tags: spring-boot

I'm trying to migrate web applications from JBoss to Spring Boot, but have some unexplained issue with VERY slow startup time.
Even simple application from Spring Boot guides - "Handling Form Submission" (packaged as a fat JAR, using Java 1.8) starts on some computers in 3 sec, but on others in 30 sec. and this is gets worse for bigger web apps (WAR-packaged with JSF, Hibernate, etc) - startup time is 13 sec vs 1500 sec (115 times more!).
Similar apps starts under JBoss or Liberty app servers starts fast everywhere.
Not sure if this is security settings, network, firewall or anti-virus tools.

Looking at the log file, it seems like application spends a lot of time on scanning JARs for TLD files and "reflection" scanning.
Strange, but this is not the issue for apps running in JBoss or Liberty - not sure if same scanning happens there.

As far as I understand, this is done per Servlet specs, but is there any way to skip scanning some JARs?
Where to add catalina.properties file in Spring Boot app, packaged as WAR, as suggested by the message?

Here are examples of log messages:

```
org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner : No TLD files were found in [jar:file:/C:/Development/workspace-Cloud/PrimeFacesDemoSBwar/target/primefacesdemoSB.war!/WEB-INF/lib/primefaces-5.3.jar]. Consider adding the JAR to the tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip property in CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.
```

...

```
org.reflections.Reflections : Reflections took 79406 ms to scan 7 urls, producing 972 keys and 4573 values
```

Comment: What version? Also that reflections log excerpt is in ms, so is under a second. Unlikely to be the bottleneck here. Can you use a profiler?